# rqt_image_view for Foxy and Galactic

Tags: ros2, image-view, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am missing something simple here,  and been at it for days now.
Installed Foxy and Galactic on Ubuntu 20.04. Both working and going through the tuts.
Attempted to add packages from repo's as exercise and would like to use my camera on PI4. guess what, pi camera incompatible with 64bit OS.
So down the rabbit hole I go.... i have a usb cam and laptop camera working with v4l2 camera (though it errors with calibration) but topics shows data. now to view the camera I need IMAGE_VIEW.

I cant get it installed with sudo apt-get ros-rqt-image-view  --- it does install something but no ros2 run image_view image view --- no package found

git cloned it into a src folder in workspace with the colcon build .. no joy

sudo apt instal rqt* ... install ok but no image view in gui under visualization. (re-install rqt)

even tried Rviz2 --- gui opens up but camera add and link to camera topic

What am I doing wrong here? How do you one view a camera in Foxy or Galactic?
I do source in terminal, and use a different terminal to run commands than the one I colcon build.

28-6-2021 (28-June)
I think I am onto something here. So I installed Galactic and Foxy from here;[docs.ros.org](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Binary.html#) It says to source it by `. ~/ros2_galactic/ros2-linux/setup.bash` .....when you do all works well enough minor glitches.
BUT then tuts(tutorials) says to `source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash` like this and then nothing works although when you check the files it is there.

So unintended X2 ros directorys? When I apt install or ros dep install image_view ends up in `tk@tk-Aspire-5820T:/opt/ros/galactic/include$`  the source directory that does not work.

Need to find a way to install "rqt_image _view" in /home/tk/ros2_galactic(or foxy)/ros2-linux/?include?....somewhere

29 June 2021

SO: the short answer is source both! First `source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash` and then `. ~/ros2_galactic/ros2-linux/setup.bash` or the one for foxy (witch ever directory you installed your version)

This is how I made sense of it:    When you install ros2 foxy or Galactic your version dependency's are installed in directory you are installing to, but the rest of ros2 is installed on your machine "system wide"
When you create a workspace you add a 'layer' where you can build or add packages with 'create pkg' or build one from source, BUT (important BUT) when you apt or apt-get something it is installed in "system wide".
Running it by sourcing your version install or work_space install bash wont find the package or installed thing.
Source "core" brings /installed things/ into terminal and sourcing "work_space setup.bash" brings version bash and w_s bash in. so you can use everything.

Source core = installed packages

source version = ros commands such as 'ros2 run'

source work space = your packages or build from source ones.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381210/rqt_image_view-for-foxy-and-galactic/) by [TK hobby](https://answers.ros.org/users/76726/tk-hobby/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-06-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SO: the short answer is source both! First `source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash` and then `. ~/ros2_galactic/ros2-linux/setup.bash` or the one for foxy (witch ever directory you installed your version)

---

Originally posted by [TK hobby](https://answers.ros.org/users/76726/tk-hobby/) with karma: 15 on 2021-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0